# ¿Hay alguna manera de actualizar el nombre de un documento de Firebase/Firestore?

Tags: firebase

Suponiendo que mi colección es algo como lo siguiente:

```
/eventos/
  180812-fiesta { ... }
  180813-reunion { ... }
  180814-concierto { ... }
```

Si quisiera, por ejemplo, cambiar el nombre del documento `180812-fiesta`. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

De esta manera es como se crean los documentos:

```
this.db.collection('eventos').doc(id).set(data);
```

Por el momento sólo se me ocurre eliminar el documento y crear uno nuevo con el nuevo nombre y los mismos datos, pero quisiera saber si hay una manera más óptima de resolver esto.

Comment: Actualmente no hay manera de cambiar el nombre de un documento. Podrías como bien indicas subirlo nuevamente con el nombre correcto y borrar el viejo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualmente no hay forma de modificar el id de un nodo (Firebase RTDB) o de un Documento (Firestore), estos son inmutables una vez que se crea el elemento.

La mejor alternativa que se me ocurre es recuperar el doc/nodo que quieres renombrar, asignarlo a un UID nuevo y luego eliminar el nodo/doc viejo.